# How can I show a new Facet only in search page? (SAP Commerce)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I created a new facet in my project but it shows on all pages and I want to show it only in /search page. Is there any way to be able to do this using search profile? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, it can be implemented in several different ways. For example:

1. Use different index configurations for different pages
2. Search on front end where it's iterating over the facets and add an
   if to check the facet name to decide when show/hide
3. In the backend, where you populate the facet list, remove from this
   list based on the page/facet name
4. Hide it using javascript when page loads

And so on.